# Wicket: Upload a File using AJAX in Modal Window

Tags: ajax, file-upload, wicket

I need to perform the file upload by clicking on the Ajax button on modal window. I have the problem, because the file is uploaded, but the process of uploading is not finished and the form can't be updated with the fileName. There is the AjaxIndicator that can't be hided after the file is uploaded. The modal window is implemented as a Panel. Here is the code:

```
uploadFile=new IndicatingAjaxButton("uploadFile"){

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) 
{
        uploadFile.getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId();
    FileUpload fileUpload =      
                  ((FileUploadFieldPanel)uploadPanel).getUploadField().getFileUpload();
    if (fileUpload != null) 
    {
            String fileName = fileUpload.getClientFileName();
            String path = uploadpath + relativeuploadpath;
        File newFile = new File(path, fileName);
        checkFileExists(newFile);
        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
            fileUpload.writeTo(newFile);
        }  
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        titleField.setModelObject(fileName);
        target.addComponent(titleField);
    }
};
    uploadFile.setOutputMarkupId(true);
form.add(uploadFile);
```

The question is: how can I update the titleField on the form with the fileName? In this case "target.addComponent(titleField);" doesn't work.

Comment: I tend to rely on the Form's onSubmit() for processing of form data (e.g. saving to the database) and only using the AjaxButton's onSubmit() method for doing the ajax manipulation (e.g. choosing which components to hide, etc).  Anyways, I presume titleField is still on the page?  You're not hiding it along with the form or anything?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a tutorial concerning this issue at http://www.dooriented.com/blog/2008/04/23/wicket-ajax-like-file-upload-on-a-modal-window/.